# Delay between ajax call and Controller method receiving

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a page in which I execute an ajax call to an ActionResult passing a JSON as data.

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        cache: false,
        url: "/ContainerPacking/_GenerateShipmentProposal",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            origin,
            containers,
            boxes
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            // execute something
        }
    });
```

Asp.NET MVC ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult _GenerateShipmentProposal(int origin, List<int[]> containers, List<Box> boxes, float GapBetweenBoxes = 0.0001f)
{
    //execute something;
}
```

This was working fine, but recently I started noticing a delay (5 ~ 10s) between the ajax call and the ActionResult being triggered.

This happens both in debug mode and in the published page.

**Do you guys have any idea what could be happening? Or how to debug/find out what could be happening?**

PS.: using `.NET Framework 4.7.1` and `JQuery 3.5.1`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing in your local environment?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Visual Studio 2019 running on my computer with debug tools enabled. But I could notice the same delay when the page is running from a server after being published.

Comment: Do you count the delay between `$ajax.beforeSend` and the time execute `_GenerateShipmentProposal`?

Comment: Yeah. I'm to see the request 'Pending' in the browser's Inspect/Network tab for a long time before the request reaches the Controller.

Comment: How do you know how long it takes to reach the Controller from the Network tab? You can only know when the response comes back, right?

Comment: Did you try to add debugger to the Controller and see which part of function takes long time?

Comment: I know through the Visual Studio breakpoints I place on the Controller Method.  The breakpoint is only triggered ~10s after the ajax request has been created. Of course I can only see this when running local, but the response times with the page published are similar.

Comment: First, Maybe try to send some empty data to see if this is faster. Second, Check if there any interception in your ajax function, such as delay the request.?

Comment: How big is the json you send? Check in network tab. Maybe the parameter binding has to much work with it.